# Distance between a segment of a circle and a point in 3D

Tags: geometry

Consider a circle segment $\mathcal{C}$ described in 3D with radius $r_0$ and central angle $\alpha$. Now this has some center, orientation and direction that describes from where we start the segment, but we can map this segment to the $XY$ plane via
$$ f : \mathcal{C} \mapsto \{ (r, \theta, 0) \mid r = r_0,\ 0 \leq \theta < \alpha\},   $$
where I use cylindrical coordinates. Now given a point $p$ in 3D, we can map it to $f(p)$ which will not necessarily lie in the $XY$ plane. How can we figure out the shortest distance between $\mathcal{C}$ and $p$, denoted $d(\mathcal{C}, p)$, or equivalently, find $d(f(\mathcal{C}), f(p))$.

I have some idea if $f(p)$ lies in the $XY$ plane. Let $f(p) = (r, \theta, 0)$ (again in cylindrical coordinates). The shortest distance is given by (I think)
$$d(f(\mathcal{C}), f(p)) = \begin{cases} |r-r_0| & 0\leq \theta \leq\alpha \\ \min( \| f(p) - e_1\|, \|f(p) - e_2\|) &\text{else}\end{cases},$$
where $e_1$ and $e_2$ are the two endpoints of the segment. That is, if the point is enclosed between the lines from the origin and the two endpoints of the segment, the distance is just the normal distance to the circle. Otherwise it is the minimum distance of the point to the two endpoints of the segment.

Then, if $f(p) = (r,\theta, z)$ does not lie in the $XY$-plane, I want to say that $d(f(p), f(\mathcal{C})) = \left( z^2 + d((r,\theta,0), f(\mathcal{C}))^2\right)^\frac12.$

It makes some intuitive sense to me, but does anybody know if it is correct? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, for any shape $S$ in the $xy$-plane, the distance of a point $p = (x,y,z)$ from it is $\sqrt{d_S(x,y,0)^2+z^2}$. You can prove this by showing the analogous equation for the distance from any point $s$ instead of the whole shape, then noting that the distance from $S$ is the minimum of all these distances.

Comment: Nice thanks! So what remains is to show that the distance I obtained for the point and circle segmnt coplanar is correct